# How can I use Database Name for sys databases in queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using this query where I am getting a list of all extended stored procedure for the Master database.

```
SELECT p.permission_name, [schema] = SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id), object_name = o.name, role_name = u.name
FROM Master.sys.database_permissions p
INNER JOIN master.sys.database_principals u ON p.grantee_principal_id = u.principal_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.all_objects o ON o.object_id = p.major_id
WHERE p.grantee_principal_id = 0 and o.type = 'X' and u.name = 'public'
```

Please can someone help me to make the database name use a variable and not hardcoding the name in the query.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(100)

    SET @dbName = '[master]'

    EXEC ('SELECT p.permission_name, [schema] = SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id), object_name = o.name, role_name = u.name
    FROM ' + @dbName + '.sys.database_permissions p
    INNER JOIN ' + @dbName + '.sys.database_principals u ON p.grantee_principal_id = u.principal_id
    INNER JOIN ' + @dbName + '.sys.all_objects o ON o.object_id = p.major_id
    WHERE p.grantee_principal_id = 0 and o.type = ''X'' and u.name = ''public''')
END
```

Comment: AGanguly can you please try this ?? . Thanks

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.